# How to properly train CNN on Full Digital Mammography

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am trying to train my Convolutional Neural Network on full digital mammography images. Here are example dimensions from a random sample: `(5832, 4104, 3)`. Which method for loading images and training the model is recommended in this case? I guess I would need to load only certain amount of images in memory so that it does not overflow. Should I use Keras `ImageDataGenerator` or TensorFlow's `TFRecords`?